# Why does this promise cause blocking in R?

Tags: r

In the following, I do not understand why the code blocks. I am expecting that printing "boom" should happen straight away, before printing "after Sys.sleep". I thought everything inside the future_promise expression should not cause blocking. What am I misunderstanding?

```
library(promises)

test <- function() {
  promise <- future_promise({
    Sys.sleep(10)
    print("after Sys.sleep")
  })
  print("boom")
}

test()
```

Ok, this does what I was after!:

```
library(promises)
plan(multiprocess)

test2 <- function() {
  future({
    # expensive operations go here...
    Sys.sleep(10)
  }) %...>% (function(result) {
    print("after Sys.sleep")
  })
  print("boom")

}

test2()
```

Comment: You are making the system to "sleep" for 10 seconds with `Sys.sleep(10)` before your function continues to run. Why do you expect `print("boom")` to work before you make the system to "sleep"?

Comment: Because I thought that future_promise would just immediately return a promise and what's going on inside would not block subsequent steps. I thought that was the idea behind promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what I was expecting:

```
library(promises)
plan(multiprocess)

test2 <- function() {
  future({
    Sys.sleep(10)
  }) %...>% (function(result) {
    print("after Sys.sleep")
  })
  print("boom")

}

test2()
```